# Android AllDay events start or finish on the wrong day

Tags: android, calendar, timezone, google-calendar-api, timezone-offset

I am working on an android app whose goal is to synchronize events between a PHP application and the smartphone. Everything work fine for “regular” events, but I have an issue with “all day” events. I followed the official Android documentation, setting the EVENT_TIMEZONE to UTC and setting timestamps for dtstart and dtend that corresponds to midnight UTC.

However, depending on the phone timezone at event creation time, when I open Google Calendar, events are:

- Showing correctly when phone timezone is GMT+2
- Starting one day before when phone timezone is GMT-11 -> GMT+1
- Finishing one day after when phone timezone is GMT+3 -> GMT+13

You should know that my tests are made in France and we currently are at GMT+2. Google Calendar is configured to use the phone timezone.

Here is a dump of event’s information before insertion :

```
06-22 17:41:02.339: V/EventEntity - addToCalendar(6535): 
Event to be inserted : 
    calendar_id=8 
    dtstart=1466719200000      ( = 24/6/2016 0:00:00 )
    eventLocation= 
    title=Server AllDay Event 
    dtend=1466805600000        ( = 25/6/2016 0:00:00 )
    allDay=true 
    description= 
    hasAlarm=1 
    eventStatus=1 
    eventTimezone=UTC
```

and here is the code of the method that does the event's insertion, where the previous log comes from :

```
Context context = AppContext.getAppContext();
ContentValues eventValues = this.getValuesForCalendar();

Log.v("EventEntity - addToCalendar", "Event to be inserted : " + eventValues);

Uri eventUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), eventValues);
this.setSystem_id(Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment()));

// === RAPPEL DE RDV ===
String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";

ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

reminderValues.put("event_id", this.getSystem_id());
reminderValues.put("minutes", 5);

// Default(0), Alert(1), Email(2), SMS(3)
reminderValues.put("method", 0);

context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);
// =====================
```

And still, when events are showing correctly, if phone timezone is changed, events span on previous or next day. The behavior in not the same with “all day” events created with Google Calendar :

Events with phone at GMT+2 :

[image: Events with phone at GMT+2]

Events with phone's timezone changed to GMT-1 :

[image: Events with phone's timezone changed to GMT-1]

So I dumped the calendar with those all day events in it, one created with my app and another created with Google Calendar :

[image: calendar dump]

As you can see, the event created through Google Calendar is set to start at 2AM and not at midnight! So I tried setting the dstart and dtend timestamps to midnight at phone timezone (ie at 2AM if phone’s timezone is GMT+2, or 23PM the day before if GMT-1) but events are still spanning to previous or next day.

In a nutshell: I’m lost and I don’t get how to have correct all day events that start and end at the right day and won’t move around the calendar when phone’s timezone changes !

Comment: Please add your code here. There might be something wrong with the conversion of the times.

Comment: @tynn I added the code that insert the event into the calendar.

Comment: The code of `getValuesForCalendar()` would be more relevant.